# Как обновить дату в таблице mysql

Tags: mysql

```
update users set data='2018-08-28 12:00:00' where UserId=999929921;
update users set data=datetime('2018-08-28 12:00:00') where UserId=999929921;
```

Дату заносит вроде, но как только собираешься что-то с этой датой сделать, например отнять он нее другую дату, сразу пишет неверный формат даты.

Как корректно добавить время в базу ?

Comment: возможно Ваш вопрос в другом - *как отнять от даты другую дату*

Comment: покажите код при помощи которого Вы отнимаете от даты другую дату

Comment: Приведите структуру ваших таблиц _с указанием типов полей_. Вот дата у вас точно datetime или может что то другое ? Ну и конечно покажите как именно вы вычитаете и что вычитаете. Я вот например не знаю такой операции как "вычитание дат" без указания типа получаемого результата. можно например найти разницу между 1 января 2018 и 10 марта 2017 в днях или минутах или в других единицах. Но единицу измерения разности дат указать придется ...

Comment: разницу дат вычисляю по этому запросу SEC_TO_TIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(now())-UNIX_TIMESTAMP(users.data)) from users where UserId=999929921;

Comment: column data имеет тип datetime

Comment: все отлично работает когда вручную дату в таблицы заносишь,а через запрос получается вот такая ошибка <failed to load>
java.sql.SQLException: Bad format for Time ' 838:59:59

Comment: нашел ошибку-sec to time к сожалению больше 86399 секунд не понимает-тоесть то количество секунд в сутках.вопрос как перевести секунды в сутки,часы и минуты в одном запросе